# Add two columns for sum of money by year

Tags: mysql

Below is my query that groups my customers together, and sums their total money spent over the last two years. Works like a charm. However I need a little more which goes over my sql knowledge.

Is there any way to select three more columns and populate it with the money they spent for each of those years (2010, 2011, 2012)?

```
SELECT  SUM(price) AS money_spent_total, co.customer_id, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, cu.email_primary, cu.phone_primary, co.date_paid
FROM customer_order   AS co
INNER  JOIN customer AS cu ON (cu.customer_id = co.customer_id) 
WHERE  cu.customer_id != 32518 AND co.date_paid > "2010-1-1" AND co.date_paid < "2013-1-1"
GROUP BY co.customer_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY YEAR(date_paid)` in addition to `customer_id`. You should also not be selecting any columns which are not in your `GROUP BY`. In addition, you can use the `BETWEEN` operator instead of `>` and `<` for your date range.

```
SELECT Year(co.date_paid), 
       co.customer_id, 
       Sum(price) AS money_spent_total 
FROM   customer_order AS co 
       INNER JOIN customer AS cu 
               ON ( cu.customer_id = co.customer_id ) 
WHERE  cu.customer_id != 32518 
       AND co.date_paid BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2013-01-01' 
GROUP  BY Year(co.date_paid), 
          co.customer_id
```

To get the columns in your original `SELECT`, you would do something like (not tested):

```
SELECT a.date_year_paid, 
       a.customer_id, 
       a.money_spent_total, 
       cu.first_name, 
       cu.last_name, 
       cu.email_primary, 
       cu.phone_primary 
FROM   (SELECT Year(co.date_paid) AS date_year_paid, 
               co.customer_id, 
               Sum(price)         AS money_spent_total 
        FROM   customer_order AS co 
               INNER JOIN customer AS cu 
                       ON ( cu.customer_id = co.customer_id ) 
        WHERE  cu.customer_id != 32518 
               AND co.date_paid BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2013-01-01' 
        GROUP  BY Year(co.date_paid), 
                  co.customer_id) a 
       LEFT JOIN customer cu 
              ON cu.customer_id = a.customer_id
```

If you were doing the `INNER JOIN` just for customer info, then it can be dropped.

```
  SELECT a.customer_id, 
       a.date_year_paid, 
       a.money_spent_total, 
       cu.first_name, 
       cu.last_name, 
       cu.email_primary, 
       cu.phone_primary 
  FROM (SELECT customer_id, YEAR(date_paid) AS date_year_paid, SUM(price) AS money_spent_total
        FROM customer_order
        GROUP BY customer_id, YEAR(date_paid)) a
       LEFT JOIN customer cu 
              ON cu.customer_id = a.customer_id
```

Lastly, if you want to group the years into columns:

```
SELECT a.customer_id, 
       a.y2010 AS '2010_money_paid', 
       a.y2011 AS '2011_money_paid', 
       a.y2012 AS '2012_money_paid', 
       cu.first_name, 
       cu.last_name, 
       cu.email_primary, 
       cu.phone_primary 
FROM   (SELECT customer_id, 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN Year(date_paid) = 2010 THEN price 
                     ELSE 0 
                   end) AS 'y2010', 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN Year(date_paid) = 2011 THEN price 
                     ELSE 0 
                   end) AS 'y2011', 
               Sum(CASE 
                     WHEN Year(date_paid) = 2012 THEN price 
                     ELSE 0 
                   end) AS 'y2012' 
        FROM   customer_order 
        GROUP  BY customer_id) a 
       LEFT JOIN customer cu 
              ON cu.customer_id = a.customer_id
```

**Result**

```
| CUSTOMER_ID | 2010_MONEY_PAID | 2011_MONEY_PAID | 2012_MONEY_PAID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | EMAIL_PRIMARY | PHONE_PRIMARY |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           1 |            9000 |            3000 |            2000 |        Bob |     Smith | bob@smith.com |    1112223333 |
|           2 |            4000 |            5000 |            1000 |        Tom |     Jones | tom@jones.com |    2223334444 |
```

### [See the demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e497/2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was trying to add 3 columns to my original query.  Anyway to do the sum and group in the select statement?

Comment: @jahrichie See my update. You may be able to get rid of the `INNER JOIN` if you were just pulling customer info.

Comment: Much closer, thanks so much for your help!!!  Last question: Is there  anyway to remove the date_year_paid break each year into their own column, and sum the price there?  IE 2010_money_paid 22222 2011_money_paid 3232 etc etc?